# Resume S3 multipart upload: PartETag

Tags: java, amazon-s3, streaming

I'm trying to implement multipart upload in Java, following this sample: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html

But my actual task is a bit more complicated: I need to support resuming in case application was shut down during uploading. Also, I can't use `TransferManager` - I need to use low-level API for particular reason.

The code there is pretty straight-forward, but the problem comes with `List<PartETag> partETags` part. When finalizing resumed upload, I need to have this collection, previously filled during the upload process. And, obviously, if I'm trying to finalize upload after application restart, I don't have this collection anymore.

So the question is: how do I finalize resumed upload? Is it possible to obtain `List<PartETag> partETags` from the server using some API? What I have is only a `MultipartUpload` object.

Comment: There are APIs to list multipart uploads and multipart upload parts.

Comment: My answer will only work if the multipart upload is still in progress. Get the list of multipart uploads `s3Client.listMultipartUploads(allMultipartUploadsRequest);` for `uploadId and keyName` > Get the list of parts for each `uploadId` `listParts(listPartsRequest)` > Get the List of part summary `getParts()` > From `Part summary` `getETag()` and `getPartNumber()`

Comment: @Nikhil Cool, this is really what I was looking for, thanks. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the list of multipart uploads in progress

```
MultipartUploadListing multipartUploadListing = 
s3Client.listMultipartUploads(new ListMultipartUploadsRequest(bucketName)); 

## for uploadId and keyName
```

Get the list of parts for each `uploadId` and `key`

```
PartsListing partsListing = 
s3Client.listParts(new ListPartsRequest(bucketName, key, uploadId));
```

Get the List of part summary

```
List<PartSummary> parts = partsListing.getParts();
```

From PartSummary getETag() and getPartNumber()

```
for(PartSummary part: parts)
{
  part.getETag();
  part.getPartNumber();
}
```

[Amazon S3 SDK Package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/package-summary.html)

[AmazonS3 client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html)